# Trigger Express Routes within Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

In my MEAN app I have Angular handling all of my client-side routes. I'm creating a login page and I have [Passport](http://passportjs.org)setup to work with Facebook. The problem I'm currently facing is that the get request for `/auth/facebook` which is triggered from a link within my Angular template when 'Login with Facebook' is clicked is handled in Express because it needs `passport.authenticate` like so:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
```

When clicked, Angular looks for a `/auth/facebook` route and because it's unable to find such a route, it falls to the catch-all/otherwise route.

If I visit `/auth/facebook` directly from the address bar in the browser however then this works fine. So how do I get Angular to communicate with Express so that it triggers the above route correctly?

Comment: show, how your link looks like

Comment: @VikramBabu <a href="/auth/facebook" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook</a>